# Numpy: how to use argmax results to get the actual max?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a 3D array:

```
>>> a
array([[[7, 0],
        [3, 6]],

       [[2, 4],
        [5, 1]]])
```

I can get its `argmax` along `axis=1` using

```
>>> m = np.argmax(a, axis=1)
>>> m
array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0]])
```

How can I use `m` as an index into `a`, so that the results are equivalent to simply using `max`?

```
>>> a.max(axis=1)
array([[7, 6],
       [5, 4]])
```

(This is useful when `m` is applied to other arrays of the same shape)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) and [numpy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html):

```
m = np.argmax(a, axis=1)
a[np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None], m, np.arange(a.shape[2])]

#array([[7, 6],
#       [5, 4]])
```

---

```
m = np.argmax(a, axis=1)
```

Create arrays of 1st, 2nd and 3rd dimensions indices:

```
ind1, ind2, ind3 = np.arange(a.shape[0])[:,None], m, np.arange(a.shape[2])
​
```

Because of the dimension mismatch, the three arrays will broadcast, which result in each to be as follows:

```
for x in np.broadcast_arrays(ind1, ind2, ind3):
    print(x, '\n')

#[[0 0]
# [1 1]] 

#[[0 1]
# [1 0]] 

#[[0 1]
# [0 1]]
```

And since all indices are integer arrays, it triggers [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), so elements with indices `(0, 0, 0), (0, 1, 1), (1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 1)` are picked up, i.e. one element from each array combined as the index.

Comment: Thanks for showing `np.broadcast_arrays`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.ogrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ogrid.html) to create a grid over all axis for your array except the one you reduced. And then just insert the `argmax` result at the position of your axis and [index](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#integer-array-indexing) your array with the result:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[[7, 0], [3, 6]], [[2, 4], [5, 1]]])
>>> axis = 1

>>> # Create the grid
>>> idx = list(np.ogrid[[slice(a.shape[ax]) for ax in range(a.ndim) if ax != axis]])
>>> argmaxes = np.argmax(a, axis=axis)
>>> idx.insert(axis, argmaxes)

>>> # Index the original array with the grid
>>> a[idx]
array([[7, 6],
       [5, 4]])
```

Note that this doesn't work for `axis=None` or in case you reduced over multiple axis.